# How many bathtubs in a min?

Tags: estimation

During the summer about $750,000$ gallons of water fall over the edge of Niagara Falls every second. If an Olympic sized swimming pool holds about $660,000$ gallons of water, how many Olympic sized swimming pools could the water that flows over the Niagara Falls fill in one minute? Round your answer to nearest 10th

Is $70$ a near-correct answer?

Comment: where do the bathtubs come into it?

Comment: I imagined they would fly in.. then fly out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number of Olympic sized swimming pools filled in one second$$=\frac{\text{volume of water flowing over per second}}{\text{volume/capacity of Olympic sized pool}}$$
$$=\frac{750000}{660000}=\frac{25}{22}$$ Hence , the number of Olympic sized swimming pools filled in one minute ($=60 \ sec$) $$=\frac{25}{22}\times 60=\frac{750}{11}=68+\frac{2}{11}\approx 68.1818181818\ldots$$

Thus, we find that $68$ Olympic sized pools are completely filled & $\frac{2}{11}$ of $69$th pool is filled in $1$ minute.

**Edit**:

> If we round the above answer to the nearest 10th, then $70$ is the near correct answer.

Comment: Well.. the question does say "Round your answer to nearest 10th"

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right

Comment: Ten**th**, not Ten